# Is there an intuitive way to understand $\frac{x\space dy-y\space dx}{x^2+y^2}=d(\arctan\frac yx)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My book says-

> $$\frac{x\space dy-y\space dx}{x^2+y^2}=d(\arctan\frac yx)$$

Specifically I am solving differential equations where I may have to transform the LHS into the RHS. Is there an intuitive way so that one can easily understand that the LHS corresponds to the RHS without explicitly evaluating the RHS?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Think about polar coordinates.

Comment: $$\frac{x\space dy-y\space dx}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\frac{x\space dy-y\space dx}{x^2}}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}=\frac{d(\frac{y}{x})}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}=d(\arctan\frac yx)$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't know much polar coordinates

Comment: @Nosrati Thanks. It helped

Comment: @Nosrati how do you get a space between $x$ and $dy$?  I can't in my answer :-( .  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Draw a right triangle with vertices at $(0,0),(x,0),(x,y)$. From SOH CAH TOA render $\tan\theta=(y/x)$, where $\theta$ is the angle at $(0,0)$.  From the derivative of the tangent function on the left side, and the quotient rule on the right, obtain the differential relation

$\sec^2\theta d\theta=\dfrac{xdy-ydx}{x^2}$.

Return to the right triangle and from SOH CAH TOA again, render $\sec\theta=1/\cos\theta=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})/x$.  Substitute into the equation above and solve for $d\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

use

$$d(f(x,y))=x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\arctan(g(x,y))=$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x,y).\frac{1}{1+g(x,y)^2}$$

Comment: This helps me to go from RHS to LHS, not from LHS to RHS, right?